# What are the values for attributes in knife ssh? ( -a ipaddress etc )

Tags: chef, knife

`Knife ssh` has the `-a` option. I was lucky to find [Knife SSH doesn't find my nodes](https://serverfault.com/questions/346418/knife-ssh-doesnt-find-my-nodes/346542#346542) to tell me that it's NOT called `IP`, as in `knife search` output, but `ipaddress`.

I would love to know where to find the doc detailing this and a reason for this being called `ipaddress` instead of `IP`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The listing of attribute values is available via:

```
knife search node "name:NODENAME" -F json
```

It's in the `automatic` attributes, eg.:

```
"ipaddress": "11.1.111.111",
```

(More on [attribute types](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Attributes) like automatic.)

You just have to know that the output without `-F json` is not giving you useful attribute names for your scripting.